# How to use win32com to manipulate PivotTables that use an OLAP cube connection?

Tags: python, win32com

I want to modify an existing pivottable to add certain fields pulled in from an OLAP connection to the rows/values/columns/filters. It does not appear to be as straightforward as manipulating a basic pivot table off static data as it's structured as a single fact table and multiple attribute tables.

Use case would be taking an empty pivot table (no fields) and dropping in user-defined fields from the pivottable fields. To start, I would like to drop "CompanyName"(from Fact table) into the first sheet's Rows.

```
import win32com.client as win32

# Define the Excel file name
excel_file_path = 'cube_1.xlsm'

# Specify the table name and field name
table_name = 'Fact'  # Replace with the actual table name
field_name = f'{table_name}.[CompanyName]'

# Create an instance of Excel
excel_app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

# Open the Excel file
workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(excel_file_path)

# Find the sheet with the PivotTable
sheet_index = 1  #first sheet
worksheet = workbook.Sheets(sheet_index)

# Identify the PivotTable (assumes there is only one PivotTable, which there is)
pivot_table = None
for pt in worksheet.PivotTables():
    pivot_table = pt
    break

if pivot_table is not None:
    # Add the field to the row area of the PivotTable
    row_field = pivot_table.PivotFields(field_name)
    row_field.Orientation = win32.constants.xlRowField

    # Refresh the PivotTable to update the view
    pivot_table.RefreshTable()

    # Save and close the workbook
    workbook.Save()
    workbook.Close()

    # Quit Excel
    excel_app.Quit()
else:
    print("No PivotTable found in the selected sheet.")
```